# CSS, Text-Decoration: Overline

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an overline effect on hover with css.  What I have so far is below.  Here's the problem I have, the over line appears directly above the text.  I want there to be some space b/w them.  Here is my site: http://baycity2014.weebly.com, and here's the effect I'm going for: http://www.hartlevin.com.  Any advice?

CSS:

```
#nav-wrap .container {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#nav-wrap .container {
    /*background:url(nav-bg-medium.jpg) repeat-x top;*/
    /*height:45px;*/
}

#nav-wrap .container ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    /* background:url(nav-saperator-medium.jpg) no-repeat right;*/
    padding-right:2px;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul > li:first-child a,
#nav-wrap .container ul > li:first-child a:hover,
#nav-wrap .container ul span:first-child li a,
#nav-wrap .container ul span:first-child li a:hover{
    border-radius:5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', san-serif;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    border: 0px solid;
    outline: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height:45px;
    /*text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #333333;*/
}

#nav-wrap .container ul li:hover {
    /*background:url(nav-saperator-hover-medium.jpg) no-repeat right;*/
}

#nav-wrap .container ul li a:hover {
    /*background:url(nav-bg-hover-medium.jpg) repeat-x top ;*/
    color: #145D85;
    text-decoration:overline;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="left_content_nav">
    <ul class='wsite-menu-default'>
        <li id='active'><a href='/'>Home</a>

        </li>
        <li id='pg886612977153583720'><a href='/about.html'>About</a>

            <div class='wsite-menu-wrap' style='display:none'>
                <ul class='wsite-menu'>
                    <li id='wsite-nav-226730044254468285'><a href='/blog.html'><span class='wsite-menu-title'>Blog</span></a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id='pg336904325932674008'><a href='/practice-areas.html'>Practice Areas</a>

        </li>
        <li id='pg342722679661255807'><a href='/press.html'>Press</a>

        </li>
        <li id='pg204649403653981064'><a href='/contact.html'>Contact</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `border-top` instead of `overline`, with some `padding-top` to pad up the spacing between the string and the top overline.

Just note that am using `border-top: 4px solid transparent;` which is just a `transparent` `border` to reserve the space, because if you won't use that, your menu items will shake on `:hover` as CSS Default Box Model counts the `border` outside the element instead of inside, which will result in element nudging..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EA8ZH/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">World</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    margin: 40px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
}

ul li:hover {
    border-top: 4px solid #f00;
}
```

---

Controlling the `width` using `:before` or `:after` pseudo, HTML stays as above..

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/EA8ZH/1/)

**CSS**

```
ul {
    margin: 40px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

ul li:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -45%;
}

ul li:hover:after {
    border-top: 4px solid #f00;
}
```

Comment: Hi, if I use border-top, can i set the length of the border-top so that the border is the same size as the word over which it hovers?  Does that make sense?  I tried border-top at first, but the over line was larger than the word.  That's why I switched to over-line instead.  In short, if I use border-top, can I control the size of the line?

Comment: @user3117275 you must be targeting the `li` and not the `a` element... you can control the same using `:before` and `:after` pseudo as well

Comment: Try using display:block to your anchor links <a> so it takes over its parent width. Your <a> width should be same as <li> width, so border is the same size as the word over which it hovers.

Answer (score 0):

they use border-top instead of overline. Please change this

```
#nav-wrap .container ul li a:hover {
   /*background:url(nav-bg-hover-medium.jpg) repeat-x top ;*/
   color: #145D85;
   text-decoration:overline;
}
```

into this

```
#nav-wrap .container ul li a {
   border-top:2px solid transparent;
}
#nav-wrap .container ul li a:hover {
   color: #145D85;
   border-top:2px solid #145D85;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul> 
    <li> <a href="#"> Item 1 </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Item 2 </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Item 3 </a>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#"> Sub Item 1 </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> sub Item 1 </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
    background:grey;
}
ul li ul
{
    display:none;
}

ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
}

ul li
{
    float:left;
    width:130px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#003366;
    text-align:center;
   }
ul li a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul li:hover
{
    border-top:4px solid white;
    margin-top:-4px;
}
ul li:hover ul
{
    display:block;
   margin-left:-50px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
ul li ul li
{
   background-color:#ffffff;
    height:100%;
    padding:10px;
}
ul li ul li a
{
    color:#003366;

}
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bssx2/21/)

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could place your menu in a `<span></span>` and set border-top for that span.